# Error al pasar variable StringVar() a UPPERCASE

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy metiéndome en la POO con python y tengo un problema:

Resulta que arme una clase donde se desarrolla la *User Interface* con *TKinter*. En la misma, el usuario debe de ingresar una patente, pero cada vez que suelta la tecla ingresada, la misma debe transformarse a *UPPERCASE*.

Este mismo código me funcionó anteriormente, pero intento hacerlo con *class* para profesionalizarlo un poco mas, y no me sale.

Adjunto el código:

```
class GUI(Tk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.geometry("500x400")
    self.title("PRUEBA TK")

def caps(self):
    self.domain.set(self.domain.get().upper())
def INI_MENU(self):
    self.domain = StringVar()
    self.lbl00 = Label(text="Dominio", font=('Helvetica', 10), bg='#e4d1b9')
    self.lbl00.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=10, pady=5)

    self.boton01 = Button(self, text="Buscar Patente", command=CENT.search_domain).grid(row=0, column=3)
    self.entry00 = Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=self.domain, relief="groove", fg="green", bd="4")
    self.entry00.grid(column=2, row=0)
    self.entry00.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.caps())
```

Así como esta el código se ejecuta, pero la función de *UPPERCASE* no aplica nada.

Quisiera saber que es lo que estoy realizando de manera incorrecta. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando pones parentesis al lado de una función, estás llamando a la función. Sin embargo lo que buscas es asociar un objeto función (las funciones también son objetos) al evento KeyRelease.

Teniendo esto en cuenta, lo que hace tu código como está es lo siguiente:

1. Se crea tu interfaz.
2. Se ejecuta la función caps en esta linea: `self.entry00.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.caps())`
3. La función caps intenta pasar a mayúscula el contenido inicial del entry, es decir una cadena vacia, y lo hace con exito. Luego devuelve None.
4. Se ejecuta `self.entry00.bind("<KeyRelease>", None)`, que es equivalente a llamar `self.entry00.bind("<KeyRelease>")`, lo cual devuelve un valor y no haces nada con el.

Como podrás ver, en ningún momento se enlaza tu función al evento.

---

Vamos a solucionar este problema quitando los paréntesis. La línea queda así:

```
self.entry00.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.caps)
```

Pero ocurrirá otro error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: caps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

A que se debe esto? A que cuando una función es llamada por un evento, se le pasa un argumento más, que es un objeto Event y tiene datos del evento responsable de ejecutar la función.

Entonces hagamos que la función acepte un argumento más, al cual llamaremos `event`.

---

En conclusión, tu código debería de quedar así:

```
class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("500x400")
        self.title("PRUEBA TK")
    
    # La función caps ahora acepta un argumento más.
    def caps(self, event):
        self.domain.set(self.domain.get().upper())
    def INI_MENU(self):
        self.domain = StringVar()
        self.lbl00 = Label(text="Dominio", font=('Helvetica', 10), bg='#e4d1b9')
        self.lbl00.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=10, pady=5)

        self.boton01 = Button(self, text="Buscar Patente").grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.entry00 = Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=self.domain, relief="groove", fg="green", bd="4")
        self.entry00.grid(column=2, row=0)
        # Los parentesis a la derecha de la función fueron removidos para evitar que esta sea llamada.
        self.entry00.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.caps)
```

Comment: Dante S. Quede totalmente conforme con tu respuesta. No solo me solucionaste el problema, sino que tambien me explicaste el porque de cada error que tenia en el codigo. 10/10 lo tuyo. Muchas gracias!!!!